# Books for dummies about car-following models

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling

I have been struck by the issue of car-following models since it can be applied to improve the travel times of a bus line and I decided to study a little about that. What "basic" books do you recommend for the study of this topic?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the following books, I hope they will be of help

[Differential Equation Models](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4612-5427-0%2F1) ------Martin Braun, Courtney S. Coleman,
and Donald A. Drew

[Traffic Flow Dynamics](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642324598)------Martin Treiber